# CreateWindowEx isn't return NULL but GetLastError returns 126 (Error:126)

Tags: windows, api, winapi, getlasterror, createwindow

Before calling CreateWindowEx(..) there isn't any error. And CreateWindowEx isn't return NULL. And interestingly window is show up after calling ShowWindow.

In code as you can see there is 2 messageboxes which writes error codes. First one writes 126, other one writes 0.

(Error 126 Means: 
ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND
126 (0x7E)
The specified module could not be found.)

After window created, window isn't working properly as you can see in the images,
if my pointer in the area where window were created it is in loading position and such things and when I move the mouse cursor into the window, it doesn't display the arrow but the resize cursor.

Sorry about my English and thanks for helps.

Codes:
WinDeneme.cpp

```
    // WinDeneme.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

const wchar_t *AppName = L"Example";
unsigned int ClassID=0;
wchar_t Error[100];

LRESULT CALLBACK Proc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    wchar_t *ClassName = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * 100);

    swprintf(ClassName,100,L"%s_%d",AppName,ClassID);
    ClassID++;

    WNDCLASS *Class = (WNDCLASS*)calloc(1,sizeof(WNDCLASS));

    Class->lpszClassName = ClassName;
    Class->hInstance = hInstance;
    Class->lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)Proc;

    RegisterClass(Class);

    HWND Win = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        ClassName,                     // Window class
        AppName,    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 200, 200,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
        );

    swprintf(Error,100,L"%d",GetLastError());
    MessageBox(0,Error,L"Error",MB_OK); //  126

    ShowWindow(Win,nCmdShow);

    swprintf(Error,100,L"%d",GetLastError());
    MessageBox(0,Error,L"Error",MB_OK); //  0

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK Proc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1));

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

stdafx.h

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

Images (I used my camera because cursors dont show up in print screen):

[Pointer is in loading position](http://oi43.tinypic.com/2ecnlnp.jpg)

[Pointer is in resizing position](http://oi39.tinypic.com/t5pt7t.jpg)

**Edit: I solved pointer issue with adding

```
Class->hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
```

But I still get Error 126 in VS2012 Express.

Comment: Your program just works fine on my Visual Studio 2010. It displays "0" in the message box and then it displays the "Example" window, Try to put SetLastError(0) before CreateWindowEx.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I did, still it displays "126". I use Visual Studio 2012, error isn't the main problem anyway, window isn't work properly. Is it working properly on VS2010?

Comment: it depends what you mean by "working properly". It does exactly this: It displays "0" in a message box. I click on OK, then another messagebox pops up displaying also "0" and a 200x200 pixel window with "Example" on the title bar pops up. This window scan be dragged around.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I solved my cursor problems with, `Class->hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);` and now it is working "properly" but still it displays "126" in VS2012 Express I dont know why.

Comment: OK, next time you ask a question please be more specific. "Not working properly" doesn't mean anything to someone reading you. You should have written something like: "when I move the mouse cursor into the window, it doesn't display the arrow but the resize cursor...". Concerning the error code 126 I'll check with VS2012 tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetLastError()` is only meaningful when an actual error occurs, unless documented otherwise.

In the case of `CreateWindow/Ex()`, if it returns a non-NULL handle, then **no error occurred**, and the value of `GetLastError()` is **undefined** (it will still contain an error code from an **earlier API function call**).

You have to call `GetLastError()` immediately after an API function exits and before any other API function is called, and **only** when the API function fails with an error unless the API function is specifically documented to return a valid `GetLastError()` value in other situations (for example, when `CreateMutex()` returns a non-NULL handle, `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` if the mutex already existed, otherwise it returns 0).

Most API functions **do not** reset `GetLastError()` before performing their work, thus preserving earlier error codes.  Only API functions that use `GetLastError()` to report extended info on success will reset `GetLastError()` if no error occurs.

Comment: Before calling CreateWindow I added "SetLastError(0)" and I still get that error.

Comment: Again, the value of `GetLastError()` **is not defined** when `CreateWindow/Ex()` returns a non-NULL window handle. You can **only** rely on the value when `CreateWindow/Ex()` returns NULL.  What you describe likely means that some other API that `CreateWindow/Ex()` uses internally was what actually failed but `CreateWindow/Ex()` handled that error internally and did not consider it to be fatal to the window's creation.  Forget whatever you are seeing in the MSDN example. **DO NOT CALL `GetLastError()` IF `CreateWindow/Ex()` DOES NOT REPORT A FAILURE! Period.**

Answer (score 0):

If `CreateWindow` returns a non-NULL value it didn't fail. There's no error, so there's no need to call `GetLastError`.

Comment: But it isn't work properly ? And there isn't any error code returned in MSDN examples.